# how to filter tableview data from mysql database?

Tags: java, sql, javafx, javafx-8

I have this interface

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqExz.jpg

and i want that when i write in the "Buscar" textfield, the data from the table changes according to the query, so far I have this code to populate the table

```
Statement st=null;
        ResultSet rs;

        try{
            Connection miConexion= (Connection) Conectar.GetConnection(); //conexion de la base de datos que se manda llamar

            st = (Statement) miConexion.createStatement();
            data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            rs = st.executeQuery("select * from accesorios ");

            for(int i=0 ; i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){

                //We are using non property style for making dynamic table

                final int j = i;

                TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));

                col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){

                    public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {

                        return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());

                    }

                });



                tableView.getColumns().addAll(col);

                System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");

            }

            /********************************
             60
             * Data added to ObservableList *
             61
             ********************************/

            while(rs.next()){

                //Iterate Row

                ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

                for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){

                    //Iterate Column

                    row.add(rs.getString(i));

                }

                System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row );

                data.add(row);



            }



            //FINALLY ADDED TO TableView

            tableView.setItems(data);

        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

            System.out.println("Error on Building Data");

        }

    }
```

If you could give me some orientation on how to do it, that would be great thank you for your help

Comment: How familiar are you with just sql?

Comment: Since you're already loading everything from the database, just [filter in the table](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/), instead of executing new queries to load the filtered data.

Comment: I'd say very haha, I tried to replace the select * from Accesorios  with select * from Accesorios where nombre= txtsearch.gettext() and with no luck

Comment: @James_D I couldn't make it work with that, I don't know how to do it with data from the database :/ I tried to sort of implement it with what I have but with no luck :/

Answer (score 0):

Good question. You are probably not the only one facing this problem, but I have not seen a similiar question. 
For me it works with database queries like this:

```
try {
//          
            statement= Main.conn.prepareStatement("Select programme,hersteller from softwarearchivtabelle where programme like '*" +
             textfieldSearch.getText() 
            + "*' OR hersteller like '*"+ textfieldSearch.getText() 
            + "*';");
            rs=statement.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()) {
                Software softwaredb= new Software(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2));
                softwareliste.add(softwaredb);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tableviewSoftwarearchiv.setItems(softwareliste);
    }
```

It would also be interesting, how to do it without sql queries but filtering just the tableview like @James_D replied, but that did not work fine with my search bar